# SSL error from AWS server in us-west-1 to eu-west-1

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04

Server's in us-west-1 region while tryin to connect https://elasticloadbalancing.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ in eu-west-1 region  curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL.

This is happening with all base images of **Ubuntu** only. If we run this on amazon link, this issue is not happening

```
ubuntu@-172:~$ curl -I https://elasticloadbalancing.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to elasticloadbalancing.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443
ubuntu@172:~$
```

This is happening from us-west-1 region only.

Answer (score 0):

We seemed to have a similar problem, after looking over the sysctl settings for amazon linux and ubuntu, we discovered that changing this seems to solve the problem:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=255
```

this was just looking at the sysctl network items between the amazon linux and our ubuntu nodes.